# Continuity of electric field in case of continuous charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

If one assumes continuous charge density inside some volume $V$, then is the electric field continuous inside that volume $V$? I know that the electric field is discontinuous whenever it passes through some charge.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field would be infinite (and reversed) at the position of a point charge, but that is usually ignored when talking about a “continuous” distribution of charge.  If your charge distribution is spherically symmetrical, you can calculate the field at each point inside.  It is continuous.  As I recall, the field inside a current carrying wire is proportional to the gradient of the charge density (again continuous).

Comment: But then why the normal component of the electric field is discontinuous at a surface, if the surface has some charge density (the normal component is discontinuous even for the continuous surface charge density)? This can be obtained by Gauss’s law. This surface is inside that volume V, where we assumed continuous charge density. This is contradictory to me.

Comment: I think the contradiction is resolved. In case of continuous volume charge density inside the volume V, the surface charge density there will be zero. Hence the normal component of the electric field will also be continuous.

Comment: If there is a surface charge density, then the charge density does not continue beyond the surface.

Comment: Yes. But if surface charge density exists at some point, then it would mean the volume charge density is infinite at that point. Is not it?